# Flashdevelop "library openfl is not installed"

Tags: flashdevelop, haxe, openfl

So I appear to be having way to many issues with flash develop and openfl, I'm not sure whether to blame my computer or my incompetence.

First I was having a problem with file associations, then whenever I would try and test a project it would open a blank web
page, now (after getting angry and leaving it for a while, and reinstalling everything) it says that openfl isn't installed.

Even though I am certain it is...

I already tried checking if there was more than one copy of the SDK installed.

Any advise or ideas are accepted, I am ripping out my own hair trying to figure it out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does `haxelib list` in the console list openfl? Is the Haxe SDK path in FD set properly?

Comment: Haxelib list does list openfl, though I must confess I have no clue how to check or change the FD paths

Comment: Update: I figured out the pathing, and it seems to be running smooth. Thank you very much for your help.